# Enabling SideLoading for apps failed with the following exception

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

When I tried enabling sideloading for one of my tenant using powershell, it failed with the following exception:

> Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall
>   within the expected range.

Any help/suggestion for troubleshooting this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code that you have used ?

Comment: I have followed this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/12/10/enable-app-sideloading-in-your-non-developer-site-collection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. It was my mistake. Missed appending 'https' in the starting of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working powershell script which I always use to enable the Side Loading feature.

```
$programFiles = [environment]::getfolderpath("programfiles")
add-type -Path $programFiles'\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
$siteurl = 'SITEURL'
$username = 'USERNAME'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'PASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
$outfilepath = $siteurl -replace ':', '_' -replace '/', '_'
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$cc = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials]$spocreds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
$cc.Credentials = $spocreds
$sideLoadingEnabled = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.appcatalog]::IsAppSideloadingEnabled($cc);
$cc.ExecuteQuery()
if($sideLoadingEnabled.value -eq $false) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'SideLoading feature is not enabled on the site:' $siteurl
    $site = $cc.Site;
    $sideLoadingGuid = new-object System.Guid "AE3A1339-61F5-4f8f-81A7-ABD2DA956A7D"
    $site.Features.Add($sideLoadingGuid, $false, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None);
    $cc.ExecuteQuery();
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'SideLoading feature enabled on site' $siteurl
}
Else
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'SideLoading feature is already enabled on site' $siteurl
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat similar to one found on the mentioned blog. Also I have  tested the same script found in the blog for another tenant and it is working fine for that tenant.